# Getting to the end of a line of code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I follow along in totoreals all the time and the instructor is so quick to get to the end of the line of code and add a semicolon.

The only ways I know how to do this is to hit the end key and that is not easy to reach, use arrow keys and push twice or more or use my mouse. For a time I remapped by end key and my cap lock key.

What are most coders using to get to the end of a line?

Comment: You mean Shift+End?

Comment: I think it is the end key. It's a bit of a reach and it's annoying bc its placed differently on some keyboards but that's the only way I know of. I use ctrl + arrow keys a lot to jump over "whole words"

Answer (score 6):

It works like this: `Home/End` takes you to the beginning/end of a line, `Ctrl+Home/End` to the beginning/end of document.

Mac might be an exception: `Command+Left/Right` arrow to go to the beginning/end of the line. If that doesn't work, try using `Fn` or Fn+Command instead of Command in the previous shortcut.

Comment: Yes I stated this in my question.

Comment: "... hit the end key and that is not easy to reach..."

Comment: Some windows keyboard has Fn key near the crtl and alt key. I guess Fn+right arrow is the ideal option for windows users.

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for certain what your instructor uses, but many coders have programmable keyboards with custom functionalities called layers. Layers are extra functions that are assigned to keys when a certain button is pressed. Shift is a good example of a layer button; when you press it, the number keys on most keyboards give symbols, and the letter keys give capital letters.

My keyboard doesn't have arrow keys; instead, it has a special button that, when held, turns I,J,K,L into arrow keys, and U/O into Home/End, respectively. I find this immensely useful for jumping to the end of a line very quickly, much like you described. It is programmed using QMK and Vial. These are awesome projects, so take a look at them if you are interested.